# how can I say if contains any of given words then show?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with data tables, and I want to filter my data table field 4. how can I filter if contains one of the `keyword` then do something?

```
    var keywords = ['aslr', 'ida pro', 'gdb', 'windbg', 'immunity debugger', 'boofuzz', 'peach fuzzer', 'winafl', 'python', 'assembly', 'penetration testing', 'exploits', 'metasploit', 'metasploit framework', 'ethical hacker', 'pentest', 'computer security', 'hacking', 'oscp', 'osce', 'osee', 'penetration testing', 'offensive security', 'red team', 'vulnerability research', 'vulnerability researcher', 'fuzzing', 'clang', 'llvm', 'address sanitizer', 'afl', 'fuzzers','penetration tester']

columnDefs: [{
            targets: 4,
            render: function (data) {
              return (data.indexOf(keywords) >= 0) ? "<span class='label label-success'>FOUND</span>" : "<span class='label label-danger'>NOT_FOUND</span>";
            }
        }
```

Comment: keywords.indexOf(data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var keywords = ['aslr', 'ida pro', 'gdb', 'windbg', 'immunity debugger', 'boofuzz', 'peach fuzzer', 'winafl', 'python', 'assembly', 'penetration testing', 'exploits', 'metasploit', 'metasploit framework', 'ethical hacker', 'pentest', 'computer security', 'hacking', 'oscp', 'osce', 'osee', 'penetration testing', 'offensive security', 'red team', 'vulnerability research', 'vulnerability researcher', 'fuzzing', 'clang', 'llvm', 'address sanitizer', 'afl', 'fuzzers','penetration tester']

columnDefs: [{
            targets: 4,
            render: function (data) {
              for (var i = 0; i < keywords.length; i += 1) {
                  if (data.indexOf(keywords[i]) != -1) {
                      return "<span class='label label-success'>FOUND</span>";
                  }
              }
              return "<span class='label label-danger'>NOT_FOUND</span>";
            }
        }
```

Comment: This answer fails when entered data is the first element in the array `aslr`. You can change the condition to `data.indexOf(keywords[i]) !== -1` to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if given string is contained in `keywords` array.

```
columnDefs: [
  {
    targets: 4,
    render: function(data) {
      return keywords.includes(data) ?
        "<span class='label label-success'>FOUND</span>":
        "<span class='label label-danger'>NOT_FOUND</span>";
    }
  }
]
```

**Live Example:**

```js
var keywords = ['aslr', 'ida pro', 'gdb', 'windbg', 'immunity debugger', 'boofuzz', 'peach fuzzer', 'winafl', 'python', 'assembly', 'penetration testing', 'exploits', 'metasploit', 'metasploit framework', 'ethical hacker', 'pentest', 'computer security', 'hacking', 'oscp', 'osce', 'osee', 'penetration testing', 'offensive security', 'red team', 'vulnerability research', 'vulnerability researcher', 'fuzzing', 'clang', 'llvm', 'address sanitizer', 'afl', 'fuzzers','penetration tester'];

function render(data) {
  return keywords.includes(data) ? 
    "<span class='label label-success'>FOUND</span>":
    "<span class='label label-danger'>NOT_FOUND</span>";
}

console.log(render("aslr"));
console.log(render("random_text"));
```